# What should have been the correct choice for this "Suggested Edit"?

Tags: support, review-suspension

I"ve just been suspended from the Review Queues and as suggested in the [What can I do in the meantime?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions) documentation I’ve revisited the tasks that led to my suspension.

There's one review particularly (a "Suggested Edit") that I cannot understand why my choice to accept it has contributed/led to  my suspension.

Here is a link to the said review:

[Review 30778327](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30778327)

**Reasons why I chose to accept the aforementioned "Suggested Edit"**

1. The suggested edit removes the original comment in the code block that reads:

   > ```
   > <-- To get into your ios subdirectory
   > ```

   To me by removing this it makes it clearer to anyone reading the post that it is not part of the preceding `cd ios` commmand, i.e. it makes it clear that it should not be entered into the command-line.

   The above comment that was omitted has then been written, albeit slightly re-worded, below the code block. In the suggested edit it now reads as follows:

   > *"This puts you into the ios subdirectory ..."*
2. Code fences were also added to the output from the `ls` command, which imho significantly improves formatting and makes the post easier to comprehend.
3. Commands that should be entered into the command-line have also been encased in code fences, which again imho significantly improves formatting and makes the post easier to comprehend.

**Note:** Points 2 and 3 above imho certainly meet the criteria listed in [Common reasons to Approve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits)

Please can anyone confirm what the correct choice should have been for this "Suggested Edit"? Why was I incorrect to accept it?

Comment: Eh, likely a mistake while handling other reviews

Comment: Ok, that looks like a perfectly fine edit and review - seconding Nick, most likely a simple mistake

Comment: Can confirm that's the case here. Worth noting for other readers that there are more reviews in play in the suspension

Comment: Another one of those "let's add code-fences and don't bother about the existing whitespaces from the previous failed formatting attempt, because everyone loves useless indentation in code blocks" edits. I would have selected "Improve", not only "accept".

Comment: @Tom - Yes that’s a valid point. I assume the code blocks you are referring to are the commands, e.g. `  pod install`. I have to admit I handled that review via a mobile device, I didn’t notice the leading spaces on the small screen.

Comment: Yes, those blocks. They all have two whitespaces in front of them. The rest of the edit is fine, but those whitespaces are annoying, at least for me.

Comment: @Zoe - yes that’s correct I should have been more explicit about that in my question. I have another four reviews in addition to the one mentioned in my OP.  For example in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30744101) I’ve clearly missed that the `i`’s should have been capitalised. Ho hum the penalties incurred for reviewing on a small screen.

Comment: @RobC plus "Can anyone help me with this?" and tag duplication in the title :) But I suppose those aren't necessarily reasons to reject if you are not a purist (where I generally lean towards).

Comment: @OlegValter That other edit has one correct change (formatting the error message), two incorrect code formattings of product names and misses other stuff to correct. That doesn't look like something only purist should reject.

Comment: @Tom yeah, the edit itself I would've rejected outright. The other two issues I mentioned, though, aren't necessarily reasons to reject, that's what I referred to. For me, they are, but as I am sure you know, the official stance is that any improvement is approval-worthy - which is, in my opinion, is a huge mistake.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a newly introduced rule on SO that if you perform 5 x reviews that are foreseen as not 100% the correct choice to make then you are suspended from the Review Queues for a month? Looking back at the many reviews I’ve performed over the years one could argue that there are other  ones that maybe should have been edited in addition to approve.

Comment: AFAIK, there's only an automatic review ban due to failing review audits. Other than that, the suspension is always imposed by a mod manually.

Comment: @AndrewT - thanks for confirming. So, presumably the threshold for a mod to impose a suspension is 5 x reviews that are not foreseen (by them) as the correct choice ?

Comment: @Tom "*They all have two whitespaces in front of them. The rest of the edit is fine, but those whitespaces are annoying, at least for me.*" when copy-pasting a command to run in a bash terminal, leading whitespace can change how the terminal operates. By default, the terminal will omit the command from being recorded in the history, so it won't be visible in the future via `history`. Which can lead to further annoyance when you need it again several days later and you can't recall what exactly you ran.

Comment: @RobC I think you are looking for a precise and clear-cut criteria for something that necessarily involves personal judgement from the mod applying the suspension. I'm sure they could consider also consider the perceived seriousness of the mistakes, how often they happened, even past suspensions for similar reasons, and probably other heuristics. In the end it comes down to a personal decision by a mod that was elected by the community precisely to make these decisions.

Comment: @yivi - yes that’s a fair comment. Just to clarify in no way am I pointing a finger nor questioning the action(s) of  a mod, I was just curious. Retrospectively looking at the other 4 x reviews that contributed towards my suspension I acknowledge that by accepting them is somewhat akin to a scenario whereby; I have considered someone who has fixed a puncture on a wheel with a worn tyre to have made an improvement. However because they didn't also replace the worn tyre their actions should not be considered an improvement.